# Bug in migration target selection

Tags: bug, status-declined, migration, moderator-tools, ssl

I tried to mod-migrate a question from [meta.sf](https://meta.serverfault.com) to here but I encountered an issue where I can't select `meta.stackexchange.com` as a target.

If I select any "normal" site like "stackoverflow", "super [user]" etc., everything works as expected, but when entering "meta.stacke", I end up with a partial list of all sites starting with numbers or the letter A, but without the SE Meta in the list.

[image]

I've tried this with Firefox on macOS Sierra and Ubuntu 16.04 and Chrome on macOS.

Comment: Looks like most of the meta sites are missing off that list, not just MSE

Comment: @ChrisF: It appears to only include sites starting with the letter A and numbers (3D printing being the only one).

Comment: I guess this is something to do with the recent HTTPS carnival.

Comment: For me, [meta.se] comes up if I start entering "Meta S" in the field (on [math.se] main and meta). Is it a picky input format or doesn't that work either on meta.sf?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks, that worked for me. But still, I believe this used to work like I tried it, but since this migration direction is so rare on [SF], I am not really sure about it.

Comment: Could be due to the change from `meta.<sitename>.szackexchange.com` to `<sitename>.meta.stackexchange.com`. Thus the URL-part `meta.stackexchange.com` now matches a boatload of sites, too many for the popup to display, while before it only matched this one.

Comment: Adding [ssl] because I suspect this has to do with the HTTPS migration

Comment: @DanielFischer - I tried both "meta Stack..." and "Stack..." and got he same results as Sven, I also managed to get an "undefined" as a single entry in the dropdown.

Comment: @ChrisF You should have migrated to "undefined", for science. I'd be curious what error that pops up.

Comment: Tried following your steps, can't reproduce.

Comment: @Oded: Hmmh. Tried again on more browsers, Safari on macOS Sierra, Firefox, IE and Edge on Win10, all with the same result.

Comment: I'll try again - did you check the developer tools for errors?

Comment: Tested with 4 different browsers - getting the correct results :/

Comment: I see what I did different - I searched for the site name - "meta stack" - no `.` - I don't think domain search *ever* worked here.

Comment: @Oded: Try to migrate to `apple.st` as an example, it will show "Ask Different", so it works for other sites. I believe that Daniel's explanation is spot on. In the end, it's not really serious anyway, as there is a working way to do this migration.

Comment: Yeah, already noticed that. Trying to see what the source data for the autocompleter is - I suspect that with the https move, `meta.stackexchange.com` matches *all* the child metas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently moved all child-meta domains to a `<sitename>.meta.stackexchange.com` to help with our move to HTTPS.

This does mean that when you search for `meta.stackexchange.com`, all child metas are returned - as their URLs contain that fragment. The autocomplete only populates the top 10 results, which doesn't include Meta Stack Exchange.

I don't see how we can fix this, given that the autocomplete should not return exact matches.

The work around is to drop the dot - searching for `meta stack` will give you far fewer results, including Meta Stack Exchange.